# Как вывести yes/no?

Tags: python

Я пытался вывести yes/no (output) но в моем коде пишет что ошибка.
Как можно вывести yes/no если в f.in заданы числа?

К примеру, Input
10 6
1 20 4 3 11 5
Output
Yes
input 9 3
8 2 6
OUTPUT = NO.

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

if sorted(a)==sorted(b)==sorted(c):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: А код в котором ошибка и собсвенно сама ошибка где?

Comment: line 1, in <module>
    a = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 6'

Comment: Да я сам только начинаю на пайтоне, около 15 дней прошло

Comment: То что вы здесь написали конечно полная фигня, но попробуйте `a = [int(item) for item in input().split()]`

Comment: Можете проверить код? a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
if sorted(a)==sorted(b)==sorted(c):
    print('YES')
else:
    print(' NO')

Comment: Посмотрите, я правильно Ваш код воспроизвел в Вашем вопросе?

Comment: Что является конечной целью? Сравнить содержимое ввода?

Comment: Коротко говоря, тут говорится о том, какой то пацан xодил в магазин, и когда он собирался отдать деньги кассиру, он сказал: "без сдачи пожалуйста". У пацана было a1, a2 ....., an рублей. Если он заплатит без сдачи то YES, а если нет то NO.

Comment: Тоесть сумму набанную монетами разного номинала мы сравниваем со стоимостью товара? Или нужно понять сможет ли чел набрать на товар без здачи своими грошами?

Comment: Верно cказано. .

Comment: Зачем вы делаете int(input()) ? int пытается все что ввели в строке превратить в одно единственное число. А вводят вам строку с несколькими числами сразу. Собственно об этом и говорит ошибка, что не может преобразовать строку '10 6' в число.

Comment: так как у вас две строки должны быть введены, то у вас должно быть 2 input, а не 3. первый читает строку, далее вы ее по пробелу (split) делите на 2 строки, содержащие отдельные числа (10 и 6). Далее вы эти 2 строки приводите уже к int, что бы они числами стали. Потом второй input и тут так же split делим по пробелам и получаем массив строк с числами, их то же переводим в числа (или циклом обходим или как вам предложили выше). И дальше уже со всеми этими данными работаем. И никакие sorted там точно сравнивать не надо, надо судя по всему считать сумму и убеждаться, что она сходится